# Como comparar dos arrays con cadenas de textos y crear uno nuevo a partir de palabras repetidas en estos

Tags: javascript, array, string, loops, comparaciones

Tengo dos arrays, uno con un texto con palabras de mas y el otro con el texto que debo comparar, el problema esta en que hay una palabra que aparece dos veces en cada array entonces al correr el codigo se me repite en el nuevo array, cuando debe aparecer segun el orden de array a validar  
Este es mi codigo:

```js
    var taskInstructions = ["Fix a bug and something something remote", 
    "Must push the new version to the cloud"];
    var actualTask = "Fix a bug and push the new version to the remote";
    //como taskInstructions es un array lo cambio a string para despues 
    //volverlo a array, solo para que sea un solo elemento, hago lo mismo
    //con el otro array
    taskInstructions = taskInstructions.toString();
    taskInstructions = taskInstructions.replace(',', ' ');
    taskInstructions = taskInstructions.split(' ');
    actualTask =actualTask.split(' ');
    var jaredTask=[];
    for(i=0; i < actualTask.length; i++ ){
    for (n=0; n <= taskInstructions.length; n++){
    if(actualTask[i] == taskInstructions[n]){
    jaredTask.push(taskInstructions[n]);
    }
    }
    }
    //lo convierto otras vez para quitar las ','
    jaredTask =jaredTask.toString();
    var change = /,/g;
    jaredTask = jaredTask.replace(change , ' ');
    //el resultado muestra la palabra 'the' repetida de a 2 veces
    console.log(jaredTask);
```

Comment: lo otro seria volver a comparar jaredTask con actualTask, solo para enviar un mensaje

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que los elementos sean unicos, puedes usar este codigo:

```
if(actualTask[i] == taskInstructions[n]){
    if(jaredTask.indexOf(taskInstructions[n]) == -1) {
        jaredTask.push(taskInstructions[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: no me funciona queda en blanco el arrya []

Comment: Intenta con la edicion que acabo de hacer

Comment: funciona un poco mejor pero me borra el ultimo 'the', por lo que no se parece al array actualTask, en algun momento probe algun codigo que me daba el mismo resultado,

Comment: Crei que eso era lo que querias.  Que solo te apareciera uno de los dos 'the'.